# .NET IIS default to index.html

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am using asp.net 4. This may be more of an IIS question.

Say my website has a subsite under the subsite folder as such:

```
    www.qinc.com/subsite/index.html
```

What I like to do instead is have the user type in

```
    www.qinc.com/subsite
```

and have page go to www.qinc.com/subsite/index.html by default vs having to type the index.html.

What is the best way to do this?

I do have something like this already in my web.config but how can I make it apply to the subsite?:

```
    <defaultDocument>
     <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="Default.htm" />
      <add value="Default.asp" />
      <add value="index.htm" />
      <add value="index.html" />
      <add value="httpredirect.htm" />
      <add value="iisstart.htm" />
      <add value="default.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
```

but I think it is doing it for the main site www.qinc.com vs the subdomain of www.qinc.com/subsite. Is there a way to tell it to apply it to the subsite as well?

Comment: What happens if you go to `www.qinc.com/subsite`?

Comment: @SLaks - Note that www.qinc.com is not the real website but an example of what is happening to the current website. If I go there the /subsite it shows all of the files in that subdomain listed. I can then click on it to go to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `index.html` to the list of default documents in the IIS site configuration.

Comment: Please note that I am already using what you mentioned but why does it not do it for the subsite?

Comment: @NatePat: Is the subfolder a separate application in IIS?

Comment: The subfolder (named subsite) is a seperate website.

Comment: @NatePat: I don't think that will inherit configuration.

Comment: Please explain how to do this @SLaks - not just an "answer"

Answer (score 1):

Further from @Slaks answer, add this to your `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```